# Velocity Template Language: How to import EscapeTool

Tags: aws-api-gateway, velocity, apache-velocity

I am trying to use `unurl` for my mapping template.

```
  $url                         -> hello here & there
  $esc.url($url)               -> hello+here+%26+there
  $esc.unurl($esc.url($url))   -> hello here & there
```

I wrote the following mapping template, but `$esc.unurl([...])` doesn't work. I couldn't figure out how to fix it. One reason might be that I am missing an import, but I don't know how to import the EscapeTool properly.

```
#set($httpPost = $input.path('$').split("&"))
{
#foreach( $kvPair in $httpPost )
 #set($kvTokenised = $kvPair.split("="))
 #if( $kvTokenised.size() > 1 )
   "$kvTokenised[0]" : "$esc.unurl($kvTokenised[1])"#if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
 #else
   "$kvTokenised[0]" : ""#if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
 #end
#end
}
```

Comment: I didn't manage to install the tool so I ended up with a different solution via Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it to [tools.xml](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html)

> Example tools.xml config (if you want to use this with VelocityView):
>
> ```
> <tools>
>   <toolbox scope="application">
>     <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.EscapeTool"/>
>   </toolbox>
> </tools>
> ```

Or add it in velocity context using [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701947/how-to-configure-velocity-escape-tool-with-spring-properties):

> ```
> ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
> model.put("esc", new EscapeTool());
> VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(
>             velocityEngine, "template.vm", "UTF-8", model)
> ```